# How to check multiple cells for value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm checking cells `A1:Ax` to see if they are `True`, if yes, I would like one cell to change its value.

Unfortunately, a regular `IF` statement can't accept a range, like: `IF(A1:A4=True, Unlocked, Locked)`.

How do I do this? I've been wracking my brain for days to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1:Ax, TRUE) = ROWS(A1:Ax), "Unlocked", "Locked")` will do the trick.

It checks if the number of `TRUE` values in the range equals the number of cells (i.e. all cells contains `TRUE`). If yes, put string "Unlocked", otherwise "Locked" in the destination cell.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, really appreciate it. This worked!